# Speeding up multiple joined tables intersection query in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to do a spatial join on multiple tables. I have one main table (*LayerData1    table in query*) and dynamically appended tables (*LayerData2 , LayerData3 - it can be more*) by user. So I find intersected polygons with main table and returning MVT. This query executed around 10s by given tile coordinates *( coordinates : 45 , 40.979896545410156 ,56.25 , 31.95216178894043 )*. But this result is useless for given tile coordinates.
So how can I speed up to query?

```
SELECT ST_AsMVT(D) from (
SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(C.geom ,st_makeenvelope(45 , 40.979896545410156 ,56.25 , 31.95216178894043,4326)) as geom  from (
 select L1.geom 
 FROM "LayerData1" L1 where st_intersects(L1.geom, st_makeenvelope(45 , 40.979896545410156 ,56.25 , 31.95216178894043,4326))
 union all 
select A.geom from (
select L2.geom 
 FROM "LayerData2" L2 where st_intersects(L2.geom , st_makeenvelope(45 , 40.979896545410156 ,56.25 , 31.95216178894043,4326))
 union all 
select L3.geom
 FROM "LayerData3" L3 where st_intersects(L3.geom  , st_makeenvelope(45 , 40.979896545410156 ,56.25 , 31.95216178894043,4326)) 
 )A inner join "LayerData1" L on st_intersects(A.geom , L.geom )
 )C
)D;
```

**Data Counts in given Tile Coordinates**

```
   Table     Count
-------------------
LayerData1   90182
LayerData2   50422
LayerData3   26631
```

**Query Explanation**

```
select L2.geom 
 FROM "LayerData2" L2 where st_intersects(L2.geom , st_makeenvelope(45 , 40.979896545410156 ,56.25 , 31.95216178894043,4326))
 union all 
select L3.geom
 FROM "LayerData3" L3 where st_intersects(L3.geom  , st_makeenvelope(45 , 40.979896545410156 ,56.25 , 31.95216178894043,4326))
```

This is my dynamically appended table section.I finding geoms whichs have geometry data in given tile coordinates.

*Example*: LayerData2 table have **5** and LayerData3 table have **3** geom in given tile cordinates .So its returning **8** geom.

```
select L1.geom 
 FROM "LayerData1" L1 where st_intersects(L1.geom, st_makeenvelope(45 , 40.979896545410156 ,56.25 , 31.95216178894043,4326))
 union all 
select A.geom from (
 ...dynamically appended table section
)A inner join "LayerData1" L on st_intersects(A.geom , L.geom )
```

In this section i joined appended data of tables on intersection wiht my main table ("LayerData1") 
Returning full of my main table("LayerData1") datas and other datas whichs have intersection.

*Example* : my main table have **10** data.LayerData2 have **5** data but **3** intersection with main table. LayerData3 have **3** data but have **1** intersection with main table.
So this query returning **14** geom data.After all  , query returning a binary mvt data

**EXPLAIN ANALYZE**

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=7196661.85..7196661.86 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=4287.619..4287.619 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                                                              
  ->  Gather  (cost=7196649.14..7196649.35 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=3978.623..4277.202 rows=3 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                    
        Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=7195649.14..7195649.15 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=3911.272..3911.273 rows=1 loops=3)                                                                                                                                   
              ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.28..7181733.12 rows=2782703 width=5964) (actual time=8.358..2970.661 rows=30332 loops=3)                                                                                                                            
                    ->  Index Scan using layerdata239_geom_idx on "LayerData239" l1  (cost=0.28..294.45 rows=10 width=32) (actual time=4.127..2366.000 rows=90182 loops=1)                                                                                     
                          Index Cond: (geom && '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000804640000000406D7D44400000000000804640000000E0C0F33F400000000000204C40000000E0C0F33F400000000000204C40000000406D7D44400000000000804640000000406D7D4440'::geometry) 
                          Filter: st_intersects(geom, '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000804640000000406D7D44400000000000804640000000E0C0F33F400000000000204C40000000E0C0F33F400000000000204C40000000406D7D44400000000000804640000000406D7D4440'::geo
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..7139698.15 rows=1159455 width=5964) (actual time=10.472..3268.137 rows=408 loops=2)                                                                                                                           
                          ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..286296.82 rows=26645 width=5964) (actual time=2.900..238.505 rows=13374 loops=2)                                                                                                                    
                                ->  Seq Scan on "LayerData236" l2  (cost=0.00..2905.16 rows=116 width=32) (actual time=1.438..1.621 rows=116 loops=1)                                                                                                          
                                      Filter: st_intersects(geom, '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000804640000000406D7D44400000000000804640000000E0C0F33F400000000000204C40000000E0C0F33F400000000000204C40000000406D7D44400000000000804640000000406D
                                ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on "LayerData232" l3  (cost=946.40..282991.31 rows=11082 width=5990) (actual time=2.277..236.752 rows=13316 loops=2)                                                                             
                                      Filter: st_intersects(geom, '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000804640000000406D7D44400000000000804640000000E0C0F33F400000000000204C40000000E0C0F33F400000000000204C40000000406D7D44400000000000804640000000406D
                                      Heap Blocks: exact=2329                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on layerdata232_geom_idx  (cost=0.00..939.75 rows=26597 width=0) (actual time=3.820..3.820 rows=26631 loops=1)                                                                                     
                                            Index Cond: (geom && '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000804640000000406D7D44400000000000804640000000E0C0F33F400000000000204C40000000E0C0F33F400000000000204C40000000406D7D44400000000000804640000000406D7
                          ->  Index Scan using layerdata239_geom_idx on "LayerData239" l  (cost=0.28..257.11 rows=10 width=32) (actual time=0.098..0.219 rows=0 loops=26747)                                                                                   
                                Index Cond: (geom && l2.geom)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                Filter: st_intersects(geom, l2.geom)                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Planning Time: 0.518 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Execution Time: 4294.236 ms
```

**What did I do to speed it up:**

1. Set all tables geom SRID to 4326
2. Added spatial index on geom column

Comment: please add the explain output for your query

Comment: @IanTurton query explanation added

Comment: :-) what @IanTurton meant is the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <your_query>`; the output is the query execution plan as produced by the PG Planner.

Comment: @ThingumaBob oh sorry :)i added